# What strategies exist to make sure a React Native app is always running?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I need some of your experience and insight in approaching this particular issue, which from what I have noticed, is quite often asked by a number of devs, but the answers are always vague.

I am developing a location based app (iOS and Android) but for obvious reasons I need to write native code as I need to update user location every hour (i.e. even if the app is in the background).

Instead of rewriting the whole geolocation that already exists in RN (and does the job really well for what I need, just only foreground), can I just implement a native method that allows me to pass it a RN javascript component as an argument and runs it in the background every hour.

If yes, are you aware of such 'run in the background' native libraries/code for iOS and Android?

PS: I know there are premium plugins that do this but they are either expensive or just an overkill. Also I would like to learn how to 'spawn' a background task like a cronjob from the client.